# Ionic error, unable to start a new App

Tags: angular, shell, ionic-framework, command, ionic3

I've been using Ionic for the past month but tried to start a new App today. It doesn't work!

I'm typing in:

> ionic start NewProject blank

What I'm getting is:

> Preparing directory .\NewProject - failed!
>   Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\NewProject'

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
npm cache clean
```

**start cmd as administrator**